# how to use text editor in SMOF (wordpress)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I tried this but, it doesn't shows the text editor. so, how can i get text editor field in SMOF??

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Legal Services",
                        "desc"      => "Upload Here content",
                        "id"        => "legal",
                        // Use the shortcodes [site_url] or [site_url_secure] for setting default URLs
                        "std"       => "",
                        "mod"       => "min",
                        "type"      => "text"
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post more details, what version are you using?

Change:

```
"type"      => "text"
```

to:

```
'type' => 'editor'
```

Comment: I think that framework is no longer supported by the devs, they merged with Redux - http://reduxframework.com. I would suggest you look into following their update docs so you can use more features.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your class.options_machine.php in the switch at row 157

```
//Wp editor input
case 'editor':

    $editor_value = '';

    if(isset($value['options']) && is_array($value['options']) ){
        $settings = $value['options'];
    } else {
        $settings = array();
    }           

    $editor_value = stripslashes($smof_data[$value['id']]);

    // Turn on the output buffer
    ob_start();

    // Echo the editor to the buffer
    wp_editor( $editor_value, $value['id'], $settings = array() );

    // Store the contents of the buffer in a variable
    $editor_contents = ob_get_clean();

    $output .= $editor_contents;

    break;
```

Since wp_editor() function echoes as default a way around it is to put it inside a buffer and then get the contents from it.

This is at least a start,